# Append String Array to a single string

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have an array of strings , extracted from a webelement. 
Array Name is 'ExtendedFeatures'

I want to make each value into one string 'fullfeatures1', separated by a comma.

eg : val1 , val1 , val3 ......

Here i have extracted the values and finally  looping through the array trying to append the string values. Without much success.

```
    int size1 = all_ExtendedFeatures.size();
    for (WebElement ele : all_ExtendedFeatures)
        ExtendedFeatures.add(ele.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < size1; i1++)
        System.out.println("Features - " + ExtendedFeatures.get(i1));

    for (int i1 = 0; i1 < size1; i1++) {

     // This is where i want to append values...
        String fullfeatures1 = str.concat(ExtendedFeatures.get(i1));

        System.out.println("Features -" +fullfeatures1);

    }
```

Comment: [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-) should do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) as following:

```
String commaSeparatedFeatures = String.join(",", ExtendedFeatures);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a String variable before start loop
    String str = "";
then you can concat string like 
    str += ExtendedFeatures.get(i1);

Comment: It would be more efficient using a StringBuilder in this case.

Comment: `str += ExtendedFeatures.get(i1)` will anyways be translated to use a StringBuilder by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

To put the values into one string **fullfeatures1** separated by a **comma** `(,)` you can use the following code block :

```
int size1 = all_ExtendedFeatures.size();
for (WebElement ele : all_ExtendedFeatures)
    ExtendedFeatures.add(ele.getAttribute("innerHTML"));
for (int i1 = 0; i1 < size1; i1++)
    System.out.println("Features - " + ExtendedFeatures.get(i1));
StringBuilder fullfeatures1 = new StringBuilder();
for ( int i = 0; i< size1; i++){
    fullfeatures1.append(ExtendedFeatures.get(i));
    if ( i != ExtendedFeatures.size()-1){
        fullfeatures1.append(", ");
    }
}
System.out.println(fullfeatures1.toString());
```